# Can I use @+id/name with the same name for multiple times?

Tags: android

This is `activity_main.xml` from a tutorial online:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >


    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/main_input"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Start"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/main_input"
        android:layout_below="@+id/main_input"
        android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="onClick"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm curious about the two lines:

```
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/main_input"
android:layout_below="@+id/main_input"
```

Seeing that I've already added the `main_input` id in the `<EditText ... />` part, I don't understand why I have to add `+` in the `<Button ... />` part again, because `+` means adding another id named `main_input`. So in this case, it added `main_input` three times, which should be a problem. But it's not, the app worked very well. Then I tried to remove `+`:

```
android:layout_alignLeft="@id/main_input"
android:layout_below="@id/main_input"
```

It worked too. So what's the difference between the two cases? Why did it work with `+` added three times?

Comment: @Nabin It worked in both cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that even if you have another `+` it sees that `main_input` was already added before and automatically reuses it rather than creating a new one.

Answer (score 1):

It already saw that main_input was a reference so it used it.

Answer (score 1):

**whenever you creating id** with **+** they assign in **R.java** that's why **+** is always prefer to assign control id first time...

&

**whenever you assign reference** from already creating **+** type id always prefer only **@id** because if you assign **@+id** then create new id every time when execute these code  in **R.java** that is not preferable....!!!!